# serializing reading multiple matrices into a single construction

Tags: r

In R, is it possible to rewrite following

```
iops1 <- read.csv('mytest_20141009_1755_iops.csv', skip=6)[2:21]
mbps1 <- read.csv('mytest_20141009_1755_mbps.csv', skip=6)[2:21]
lat1  <- read.csv('mytest_20141009_1755_lat.csv', skip=6)[2:21]

iops2 <- read.csv('mytest2_20141010_1034_iops.csv', skip=6)[2:21]
mbps2 <- read.csv('mytest2_20141010_1034_mbps.csv', skip=6)[2:21]
lat2  <- read.csv('mytest2_20141010_1034_lat.csv', skip=6)[2:21]

iops3 <- read.csv('mytest_20141011_2050_iops.csv', skip=6)[2:21]
mbps3 <- read.csv('mytest_20141011_2050_mbps.csv', skip=6)[2:21]
lat3  <- read.csv('mytest_20141011_2050_lat.csv', skip=6)[2:21]
```

Into something like (pseudo code)

```
[iops1,mbps1,lat1, iops2,mbps2,lat2, ... ]
 <- serial(read.csv, ('file1.csv','files2.csv','file3.csv',...), skip=6)[2:21]
```

I wrote my first R script and it works as expected, just looking around 
if it's possible to express some parts of it better. I know R has an efficient 
syntax. Thanks!

Comment: Speed would be improved with colCasses specification. Could use "NULL" as first entry to drop the first column. `..., colClasses=c("NULL", rep(20, "numeric")) ...)`. You could use lapply to load all results into a single list, but whether that makes sense depends on the overall nature of the task which you have not described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how one would do specifically what you ask but you could write a loop to read in files and name them. I typically name my files that I'm going to read in in such as fashion as to allow me to loop through them. So if you can rename your 20141009_1755, 20141010_1034, and 20141011_2050 to 1,2,3 then the following works and you can loop through a large # of files. Otherwise you can still do below but with slightly amended code.

```
file.names<-c('iops','mbps','lat')
for (i in 1:3) {
    for (j in file.names) {
        file<-read.csv(paste0('mytest_',i,j,'.csv'),skip=6)[2:21]) #read in your file
        assign(paste0(j,i),file) #rename your dataframe
    }
}
```